# Restore a deleted CSS from loaded page on localhost in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, recovery

I was working on web project, and when i pushed my changes, my files disappeared because of bad manipulations. Now, I've lost my files, but my page is still Firefox memory, so I could copy the HTML code. But I cannot copy the CSS ! I've tried to recover deleted file using Quetek's utility, but the files are corrupted, and in the css I could see "heade", "master"... But not my CSS. Please help me !! I didn't closed Firefox. Vinz243

Comment: The CSS file were corrupted, but i browsed .git directory (in objects), some files were just chinese (real chinese), but i found some old version of my css file. But not the last. Keep searching

Comment: It is resolved ! In eclipse, i could browse my commits (right click in the repo), and i found the last commit, with the latest changes ! Thank you, Git.
Thank you any way for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just discovered why ***all developers need to use source control*** (Git, Mercurial, Subversion, etc.)

That said, this isn't really a programming question and doesn't fit well with Stack Overflow's guidelines.  The latest version of FireFox (the only one I've checked) lets you choose "Web Developer" from the menu, then click on the "Style Editor" choice on the top of the newly opened area.  In there, you can see the css resources it is using.

Comment: My CSS doesn't appear, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has a built in Inspector tool you can access by right-clicking an element and selecting Inspect Element from the drop down menu that appears.

From here you can select Style Editor menu to the right of the Inspector tab to view the css of the rendered page